# Listing datasets doesn't bring back the correct result

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis-10.2

If I do a ListDatasets() in python, then I don't get the correct result in the list except for datasets belong to other schema owners, so why can I still see the datasets in ArcCatalog.

The code is staightforward:

```
workspace = r'Database Connections\\enidb.sde'
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
dslist = arcpy.ListDatasets()
```

The dslist is empty bar the CULTURAL.ESRI_DATASETS - I should be able to see all the ENIDB ones as I am logged in as that schema owner:

[image]
[image]

Any clues folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem just use :

arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()

and this clears any locks.